# Disable specific behavior for [name].html - [name]_files combo in Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, filesystems, file-management, copy-paste

In Windows (7, at least) there's specific behavior for a [name].html file and [name]_files folder in the same parent folder. Normally when you copy and paste a file/folder in the same parent folder as the source file/folder you get a duplicate:

- C:\parent_folder\

  - example.html

*Select `example.html`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, you get:*

- C:\parent_folder\

  - example.html
  - example - Copy.html

---

**Not** so when the situation is the following:

- C:\parent_folder\

  - example_files\
  - example.html

And you try to do the same thing as above, you get:

[image: Windows refuses to duplicate the file]

---

My questions are these:

- First and foremost, is there a way to disable this?
- Why does Windows do this? What else is different when you have a [name].html - [name]_files combo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with connected files. Here is an excerpt from MSDN:

> With Windows 2000 or later, it is possible to connect an HTML file
>   with a folder that contains related files such as Graphics Interchange
>   Format (GIF) images or style sheets. If file connection is enabled,
>   when you move or copy the HTML file, the connected folder and all of
>   its files are also moved or copied. Conversely, if you move the folder
>   with the related files, the HTML file is also moved.

(c) [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/bb762164(v=vs.85).aspx)

You can disable this behavior by enabling registry value NoFileFolderConnection to 1 in this registry key.

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer

```
Value: NoFileFolderConnection
Type : REG_DWORD
Data : 1
```

Also, see [Operations on an HTML file or folder apply to similarly named folder or HTML file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/252721)

As for question #2, I don't know why Windows does this. Logically, it would have been better if Windows created a folder named `Example - Copy_files` when you create a copy of the `Example.html` file.. but it doesn't do that for some reason.

Comment: Maybe add that NoFileFolderConnection should be a `DWORD`? And that you need to log out and back in again before it works? Apart from that, great answer!

Comment: Yes. It's a DWORD value, a re-login is suggested after the edit.